# How do I post to existing JSON data in DOM with user input in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, dom

I am pulling from an external JSON file and posting the contents to the dom as a series of "cards." I have a section that allows user input to add to the cards. My question is how do I add what a user puts in to the existing cards and have it look the same?

Below is what I have in the HTML. The first controller is the template used for posting the JSON data. The second controller is the input section. It gathers the user input and stores it in the `master` variable.

How do I then use that to post it with the rest of the JSON data? I just copied and pasted the user input section from the AngularJS website and changed a couple things but I may be totally off with it.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as $ctrl">
<button class="index" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails">Index</button>
<button class="add" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails">Add</button>    
<ul class="cards" ng-hide="showDetails">
        <li class="list" ng-hide="showDogs" style="list-style:none;" ng-repeat="dog in $ctrl.dogs">
            <strong>{{dog.breed}}</strong>
            <br>
        <strong>Description:</strong> <span>{{dog.description}}</span>
            <br>
        <strong>Size:</strong> <span style="color:blue;">{{dog.size}}</span>
            <br>
        <strong>Lifespan:</strong> <span style="color:green;">{{dog.lifespan}}</span>
            <br><br>
        <button class="delete" ng-click="showDogs = !showDogs">Delete</button>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div ng-controller="ExampleController" class="addData" ng-show="showDetails">
        <h1>Add Your Own Breed</h1>
      <form novalidate class="simple-form">
        <label>Breed: <br><input class="inputBox" type="text" ng-model="user.breed" /></label><br />
        <label>Description: <br><input class="inputBox" id="description" type="text" ng-model="user.description" /></label><br />
        <label>Size: <br><input class="inputBox" type="text" ng-model="user.size" /></label><br />
            <label>Lifespan: <br><input class="inputBox" type="text" ng-model="user.lifespan" /></label><br />
        <input type="button" ng-click="reset()" value="Reset" />
        <input type="submit" ng-click="update(user)" value="Save" />
      </form>
      <pre>user = {{user | json}}</pre>
      <pre>master = {{master}}</pre>
    </div>
    </div>
```

If it's helpful, here's the controller in the JS file for the "ExampleController" controller:

```
  // controller to for the Add Breeds page
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.master = {};

      $scope.update = function(user) {
        $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
      };

      $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
      };

      $scope.reset();
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using an array :
Take 1 array for dogs
Push initial value in dog[]
and use ng-repeat for displaying on the HTML

Take user input and push to dogs array

```js
$scope.dogs = [];

dog = {
   "breed" : "some",
   "description" : "some",
   "size" : "some",
   "lifespan" : "some",
}

dogs.push(dog);
```

```html
<ul class="cards" ng-hide="showDetails" data-ng-repeat="dog in dogs">
    <li class="list" ng-hide="showDogs" style="list-style:none;" ng-repeat="dog in $ctrl.dogs">
        <strong>{{dog.breed}}</strong>
        <br>
        <strong>Description:</strong> <span>{{dog.description}}</span>
        <br>
        <strong>Size:</strong> <span style="color:blue;">{{dog.size}}</span>
        <br>
        <strong>Lifespan:</strong> <span style="color:green;">{{dog.lifespan}}</span>
        <br><br>
        <button class="delete" ng-click="showDogs = !showDogs">Delete</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: For some reason adding the `data-ng-repeat="dog in dogs"` prevents any of the JSON from printing to the page.

Comment: Can you try with "ng-repeat" only